# Display time in hrs and minutes format using lubridate package in R : Dataframe Issue

Tags: r, time, lubridate

When I am trying change the data format of time to **Hrs and Minutes**. I am able to achieve it using **lubridate** package in R. The function i am using is **hm()**. However, when I try to print it in console it works just fine as mentioned below, But If I view my **dataframe I do not see H M S format at all**, all I get is bunch of 0s. I am using RStudio.

```
d1$cr_hr <- hm(d1$cr_time)
tail(d1$cr_hr,10)
## [1] "16H 11M 0S" "16H 14M 0S" "16H 15M 0S" "16H 17M 0S" "16H 19M 0S" "16H 22M 0S" "16H 25M 0S"
## [8] "16H 27M 0S" "16H 29M 0S" "16H 33M 0S"

tail(d1$cr_time)
[1] "16:19" "16:22" "16:25" "16:27" "16:29" "16:33"
```

Comment: Please provide `dput(tail(d1$cr_hr,10))`. Also what exactly doesn't work? `View(d1$cr_hr)`? Are you using Rstudio? They have many bugs in their `View`, what `utils::View(d1$cr_hr)` gives you?

Comment: I have updated the question with the data description of d1$cr_time and I am using R Studio, but as hrbrmstr described the data is exactly in the same format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hm` transforms a character or numeric vector into a `Period` object. i.e.:

```
str(hm("10:30"))
## Formal class 'Period' [package "lubridate"] with 6 slots
##   ..@ .Data : num 0
##   ..@ year  : num 0
##   ..@ month : num 0
##   ..@ day   : num 0
##   ..@ hour  : num 10
##   ..@ minute: num 30
```

thus, your zeroes. (look at `?"Period-class"` in lubridate help). `Period`'s "print" method just makes it readable at a console view or R "print".

We have no idea what `d1$cr_time` looks like since you didn't provide any sample data. If it's just clock-format "H:M:S":

```
cr_time <- c("16:11:33", "16:14:33", "16:15:33", "16:17:33", "16:19:33", 
             "16:22:33", "16:25:33", "16:27:33", "16:29:33", "16:33:33")
```

then you can `gsub` your way to just "H:M":

```
gsub(":[[:digit:]]{2}$", "", cr_time)
```

If it's something else, please post your example data.

Comment: I can achieve the same using d1$cr_time<-strftime(d1$cr_on, format="%H:%M") where d1$cr_on is date time format(POSIXct) but I was wondering if I could get text (Hrs and Minutes) around these numbers.

Comment: Your answer helped me, it was the format issue so I used the below code to make it work. `d1$crtime<-format(d1$crtime,format="%H-%M")`